# How to write a macro to access data from memory in C?

Tags: c, macros, memory-address, c-preprocessor

Last week I had an interview. I was asked to write a macro to read a memory location (say `0x2000`).
I wrote the code in normal programming, but I could not write the macro.
Please help me figure out how to write the macro for the code below:

```
char *address = (char*)0x2000; // address is a pointer to address 3000 char val

*address = 36; // write 36 to 8 bit location at address

val = *address; // read 8 bit value from address
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#define READ_CHAR_AT(address) *((char *) (address))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#define MEMVAL(addr) ((*((char*)(addr)) = 36), *((char*)(addr)))
```

If you want to set it to 36 then read the value again, use the sequence operator. (&& would also be ok, since 36 is true...)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define memval(addr) *((char*)(addr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define VALUE_AT_ADDRESS(address,type) *((type*) (address))
```